# How/where to implement an interface

Tags: java, eclipse, interface

When I try to compile my code in eclipse, it says "must implement interface DataStructureIterator extends java.util.Iterator.remove()"  Please help, I don't  know where to implement it and it fails in a continuous loop.

```
public class DataStructure {

    private final static int SIZE = 15;


    private int [] arrayOfInts = new int [SIZE];


    public DataStructure () 
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++ )
        {
            arrayOfInts[i] = i;
        }   
    }
    public void printEven()
    {

        DataStructureIterator iterator = this.new EvenIterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    interface DataStructureIterator extends java.util.Iterator<Integer> 
    { 

    } 



    private class EvenIterator implements DataStructureIterator 
    {

        private int nextIndex = 0;

        public boolean hasNext() {

            return (nextIndex <= SIZE - 1);
        }        

        public Integer next() 
        {               
            Integer retValue = Integer.valueOf(arrayOfInts[nextIndex]);

            nextIndex += 2;
            return retValue;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`EvenIterator` is declared as (indirectly) implementing the `Iterator<Integer>` interface, so it must implement [the `Iterator.remove` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html). That is: it must provide a public method named `remove` that returns `void` and is not declared as throwing any checked exceptions.

If you don't want `EvenIterator` to support element removal, you can just write:

```
public void remove()
{
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```